# Control an interactive process using D

Tags: d

I have a program that waits for a line of standard input, and then, after processing it (which takes a relatively long time), emits an answer. The program will take input until the input stream closes.

How could I control that program from D? In other words how could I

1. Give the child process a line of standard input.
2. Wait for the child process to answer.
3. Repeat, until I have exhausted the inputs I want to give to it.

I tried the following code, but not surprisingly, it waits for the child process to finish entirely, and then prints the output all at once:

```
module main;

import std.file;
import std.path;
import std.process;
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] args)
{
    string[] inputs = ["test string 1", "test string 2"];

    auto pipes = pipeProcess(buildPath(getcwd(), "LittleTextProcessingApp"), Redirect.all);
    scope(exit) wait(pipes.pid);

    foreach(input; inputs)
    {
        pipes.stdin.writeln(input);
    }
    pipes.stdin.close;

    foreach(line; pipes.stdout.byLine)
    {
        writeln(line);
    }
}
```

That is, it prints, after a one-second delay,

> The following was input 500 ms ago: test string 1
>     The following was input 500 ms ago: test string 2

The desired behavior is that it print

> The following was input 500 ms ago: test string 1

after a half second, and the second line 500 ms later.

The source code for the program I am testing as the child process is as follows:

```
module main;

import std.stdio;
import core.thread;

void main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(input; stdin.byLine)
    {
        auto duration = 500.msecs;
        stderr.writefln("Doing something for %s....", duration);
        Thread.sleep(duration);
        writefln("The following was input %s ago: %s", duration, input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is the child process.
After `writefln`, the output is not flushed by default.
Instead, it is kept in a buffer (a few kilobytes long).
This is common technique (not specific to D) which can greatly improve speed when, for example, writing a large file to HDD in lots of few-byte chunks.

To flush the buffer, use `stdout.flush()` every time you want the output to appear immediately.
Adding that line after the last `writefln` in your child example's code fixes the situation in the example.

Comment: I guess to be safe, I should use stdout.flush() both in the child process and in the parent process. (At least that was necessary to use the internal output buffer in Xamarin, which is what I was using.)

Comment: I noticed when not directly running in a shell D makes the buffer fill up quite a while until actually flushing.